# Reconfigured Grid does not work on ExtJS 4.2

Tags: node.js, express, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to use a reconfigure grid on extjs 4.2, you can find its example with its original code [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/) (go to **Reconfigure Grid** under **Grids**) but it doesn't find the file Office.js and Empolyee.js.

Code:

```
function init() {   
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {
            const grid = Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.Reconfigure', {
                extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

                requires: [
                    'Ext.grid.*',
                    'Ext.layout.container.HBox',
                    'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
                    'KitchenSink.model.grid.Office',
                    'KitchenSink.model.grid.Employee'
                ], 
                xtype: 'reconfigure-grid',


                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },

                width: 500,
                height: 330,

                lastNames: ['Jones', 'Smith', 'Lee', 'Wilson', 'Black', 'Williams', 'Lewis', 'Johnson', 'Foot', 'Little', 'Vee', 'Train', 'Hot', 'Mutt'],
                firstNames: ['Fred', 'Julie', 'Bill', 'Ted', 'Jack', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mike', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Travis', 'Kelly', 'Sara'],
                cities: ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix', 'San Antonio', 'San Diego', 'Dallas', 'San Jose'],
                departments: ['Development', 'QA', 'Marketing', 'Accounting', 'Sales'],

                initComponent: function(){
                    Ext.apply(this, {
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            defaultType: 'button',
                            items: [{
                                itemId: 'showOffices',
                                text: 'Show Offices',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.onShowOfficesClick
                            }, {
                                itemId: 'showEmployees',
                                margin: '0 0 0 10',
                                text: 'Show Employees',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.onShowEmployeesClick
                            }]
                        }, {
                            margin: '10 0 0 0',
                            xtype: 'grid',
                            flex: 1,
                            columns: [],
                            viewConfig: {
                                emptyText: 'Click a button to show a dataset',
                                deferEmptyText: false
                            }
                        }]    
                    });
                    this.callParent();
                },

                onShowOfficesClick: function(){
                    var grid = this.down('grid');

                    Ext.suspendLayouts();
                    grid.setTitle('Employees');
                    grid.reconfigure(this.createOfficeStore(), [{
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'City',
                        dataIndex: 'city'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Total Employees',
                        dataIndex: 'totalEmployees',
                        width: 140
                    }, {
                        text: 'Manager',
                        dataIndex: 'manager',
                        width: 120
                    }]);
                    this.down('#showEmployees').enable();
                    this.down('#showOffices').disable();
                    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);  
                },

                onShowEmployeesClick: function(){
                    var grid = this.down('grid');

                    Ext.suspendLayouts();
                    grid.setTitle('Employees');
                    grid.reconfigure(this.createEmployeeStore(), [{
                        text: 'First Name',
                        dataIndex: 'forename'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Last Name',
                        dataIndex: 'surname'
                    }, {
                        width: 130,
                        text: 'Employee No.',
                        dataIndex: 'employeeNo'
                    }, {
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Department',
                        dataIndex: 'department'
                    }]);
                    this.down('#showOffices').enable();
                    this.down('#showEmployees').disable();
                    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
                },

                createEmployeeStore: function(){
                    var data = [],
                        i = 0,
                        usedNames = {},
                        name;

                    for (; i < 20; ++i) {
                        name = this.getUniqueName(usedNames);
                        data.push({
                            forename: name[0],
                            surname: name[1],
                            employeeNo: this.getEmployeeNo(),
                            department: this.getDepartment()
                        });
                    }
                    return new Ext.data.Store({
                        model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Employee,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                createOfficeStore: function(){
                    var data = [],
                        i = 0,
                        usedNames = {},
                        usedCities = {};

                    for (; i < 7; ++i) {
                        data.push({
                            city: this.getUniqueCity(usedCities),
                            manager: this.getUniqueName(usedNames).join(' '),
                            totalEmployees: Ext.Number.randomInt(10, 25)
                        });
                    }
                    return new Ext.data.Store({
                        model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Office,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                // Fake data generation functions
                generateName: function(){
                    var lasts = this.lastNames,
                        firsts = this.firstNames,
                        lastLen = lasts.length,
                        firstLen = firsts.length,
                        getRandomInt = Ext.Number.randomInt,
                        first = firsts[getRandomInt(0, firstLen - 1)],
                        last = lasts[getRandomInt(0, lastLen - 1)];

                    return [first, last];
                },

                getUniqueName: function(used) {
                    var name = this.generateName(),
                        key = name[0] + name[1];

                    if (used[key]) {
                        return this.getUniqueName(used);
                    }

                    used[key] = true;
                    return name;
                },

                getCity: function(){
                    var cities = this.cities,
                        len = cities.length;

                    return cities[Ext.Number.randomInt(0, len - 1)];
                },

                getUniqueCity: function(used){
                    var city = this.getCity();
                    if (used[city]) {
                        return this.getUniqueCity(used);
                    }

                    used[city] = true;
                    return city;
                },

                getEmployeeNo: function() {
                    var out = '',
                        i = 0;
                    for (; i < 6; ++i) {
                        out += Ext.Number.randomInt(0, 7);
                    }
                    return out;
                },

                getDepartment: function() {
                    var departments = this.departments,
                        len = departments.length;

                    return departments[Ext.Number.randomInt(0, len - 1)];
                }
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout: 'border',
                title: "",
                region: 'center',
                collapsible: false,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: {
                    items: grid
                },  
            });
        }   
    });
}
```

When I try to open it on Google Chrome, I get these errors:

[image]

I have already tried to download both files from [here](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/extjs/tree/master/examples/kitchensink/classic/samples/model/grid) and I put them somewhere of my project folder but the issue still persists.

Also I've tried to remove `KitchenSink.model.grid.Office` and `KitchenSink.model.grid.Office` from `requires` and then it works but the buttons don't work. I get this when I click on them:

[image]

Note: I'm using Node.js with Express for displaying my website since it's going to have server connections. So that's my folders tree:

```
-assets
|-css
 |-main.css
 |-util.css
|-img
|-js
 |-adminPage.js (My ExtJS file)
 |-jquery-3.2.1.min.js
-views
 |-adminPage.ejs (I call adminPage.js from this file)
 |-login.ejs
-dbConnection.js
-server.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use view you need to do `Ext.create` instead of `Ext.define`.

> Instantiate a class by either full name, alias or alternate name. If Ext.Loader is enabled and the class has not been defined yet, it will attempt to load the class via synchronous loading.

Ext.define

> Defines a class or override. **Doesn't return anything**

Btw. you should require the `view definitions` in `Ext.app.Controller`, and use `alias`/`xtype` parameter for auto-creating views by shortcut.

```
function init() {   
    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {
            Ext.define('KitchenSink.view.grid.Reconfigure', {
                extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

                requires: [
                    'Ext.grid.*',
                    'Ext.layout.container.HBox',
                    'Ext.layout.container.VBox',
                    'KitchenSink.model.grid.Office',
                    'KitchenSink.model.grid.Employee'
                ], 
                xtype: 'reconfigure-grid',


                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },

                width: 500,
                height: 330,

                lastNames: ['Jones', 'Smith', 'Lee', 'Wilson', 'Black', 'Williams', 'Lewis', 'Johnson', 'Foot', 'Little', 'Vee', 'Train', 'Hot', 'Mutt'],
                firstNames: ['Fred', 'Julie', 'Bill', 'Ted', 'Jack', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mike', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Travis', 'Kelly', 'Sara'],
                cities: ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia', 'Phoenix', 'San Antonio', 'San Diego', 'Dallas', 'San Jose'],
                departments: ['Development', 'QA', 'Marketing', 'Accounting', 'Sales'],

                initComponent: function(){
                    Ext.apply(this, {
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            defaultType: 'button',
                            items: [{
                                itemId: 'showOffices',
                                text: 'Show Offices',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.onShowOfficesClick
                            }, {
                                itemId: 'showEmployees',
                                margin: '0 0 0 10',
                                text: 'Show Employees',
                                scope: this,
                                handler: this.onShowEmployeesClick
                            }]
                        }, {
                            margin: '10 0 0 0',
                            xtype: 'grid',
                            flex: 1,
                            columns: [],
                            viewConfig: {
                                emptyText: 'Click a button to show a dataset',
                                deferEmptyText: false
                            }
                        }]    
                    });
                    this.callParent();
                },

                onShowOfficesClick: function(){
                    var grid = this.down('grid');

                    Ext.suspendLayouts();
                    grid.setTitle('Employees');
                    grid.reconfigure(this.createOfficeStore(), [{
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'City',
                        dataIndex: 'city'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Total Employees',
                        dataIndex: 'totalEmployees',
                        width: 140
                    }, {
                        text: 'Manager',
                        dataIndex: 'manager',
                        width: 120
                    }]);
                    this.down('#showEmployees').enable();
                    this.down('#showOffices').disable();
                    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);  
                },

                onShowEmployeesClick: function(){
                    var grid = this.down('grid');

                    Ext.suspendLayouts();
                    grid.setTitle('Employees');
                    grid.reconfigure(this.createEmployeeStore(), [{
                        text: 'First Name',
                        dataIndex: 'forename'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Last Name',
                        dataIndex: 'surname'
                    }, {
                        width: 130,
                        text: 'Employee No.',
                        dataIndex: 'employeeNo'
                    }, {
                        flex: 1,
                        text: 'Department',
                        dataIndex: 'department'
                    }]);
                    this.down('#showOffices').enable();
                    this.down('#showEmployees').disable();
                    Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
                },

                createEmployeeStore: function(){
                    var data = [],
                        i = 0,
                        usedNames = {},
                        name;

                    for (; i < 20; ++i) {
                        name = this.getUniqueName(usedNames);
                        data.push({
                            forename: name[0],
                            surname: name[1],
                            employeeNo: this.getEmployeeNo(),
                            department: this.getDepartment()
                        });
                    }
                    return new Ext.data.Store({
                        model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Employee,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                createOfficeStore: function(){
                    var data = [],
                        i = 0,
                        usedNames = {},
                        usedCities = {};

                    for (; i < 7; ++i) {
                        data.push({
                            city: this.getUniqueCity(usedCities),
                            manager: this.getUniqueName(usedNames).join(' '),
                            totalEmployees: Ext.Number.randomInt(10, 25)
                        });
                    }
                    return new Ext.data.Store({
                        model: KitchenSink.model.grid.Office,
                        data: data
                    });
                },

                // Fake data generation functions
                generateName: function(){
                    var lasts = this.lastNames,
                        firsts = this.firstNames,
                        lastLen = lasts.length,
                        firstLen = firsts.length,
                        getRandomInt = Ext.Number.randomInt,
                        first = firsts[getRandomInt(0, firstLen - 1)],
                        last = lasts[getRandomInt(0, lastLen - 1)];

                    return [first, last];
                },

                getUniqueName: function(used) {
                    var name = this.generateName(),
                        key = name[0] + name[1];

                    if (used[key]) {
                        return this.getUniqueName(used);
                    }

                    used[key] = true;
                    return name;
                },

                getCity: function(){
                    var cities = this.cities,
                        len = cities.length;

                    return cities[Ext.Number.randomInt(0, len - 1)];
                },

                getUniqueCity: function(used){
                    var city = this.getCity();
                    if (used[city]) {
                        return this.getUniqueCity(used);
                    }

                    used[city] = true;
                    return city;
                },

                getEmployeeNo: function() {
                    var out = '',
                        i = 0;
                    for (; i < 6; ++i) {
                        out += Ext.Number.randomInt(0, 7);
                    }
                    return out;
                },

                getDepartment: function() {
                    var departments = this.departments,
                        len = departments.length;

                    return departments[Ext.Number.randomInt(0, len - 1)];
                }
            });

            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout: 'border',
                title: "",
                region: 'center',
                collapsible: false,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'reconfigure-grid'
                }]
            });
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping :) but unfortunately I gave up and I decided to code the website using JS/CSS natively as I was not receiving any reply and I needed to do it as soon as possible. Anyway, I will mark my question as solved and I will save your answer in case I need it in the future.